# Databricks Delta Lake table history Error: AnalysisException: Cannot time travel Delta table to version 1. Available versions: [10, 22]

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, timedelta, delta-lake

Can someone let me know why I can no longer version number one from Databricks History Version

When I execute the following code:

```
df = spark.read.format("delta").option("versionAsof", 1).load(saveloc)
```

I get the error:

```
AnalysisException: Cannot time travel Delta table to version 1. Available versions: [10, 22].
```

AS you can see the earliest version is 10. However, when I execute this same code a few days ago I was able to see version 1.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the old versions were recycled by applying the VACUUM command to your table - versions in the Delta table aren't kept indefinitely - there are retention settings so old versions & data files are removed.  You can find more about it in the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/vacuum.html).

Comment: Hi @Alex, I have read the documentation you suggested. I read that the default retention threshold for data files is 7 days. So, how does Databricks determine at which point it will start the version number? In my case the new version number now starts at Version 10.

Comment: usually it's based on the Delta log checkpoints - check the property about log retention: `delta.logRetentionDuration`